# Django admin annotation is multiplied if search_field (by related FK),

Tags: django, django-admin

i have problem with multiplation of annotation...

if i use search_field by email `useremail__email` (related fk of user model) ... then my annotation is multipled
the problem is if the table with profileemails is joined (without search it works just good)

in example:
i have user named admin and emails.. admin1, admin2, admin3
then search is done by `admin`
the result is sum * 3 (because 3 emails)

my model:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()


class SubPayment(models.Model):
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()


class UserEmail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

in admin i have User model where i want to display sum and count of subpayments:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("username", "payment_count", "payment_sum")
    search_fields = (
        'useremail__email',
        'username'
    )

def payment_count(self, obj):
    return obj.payment_count

def payment_sum(self, obj):
    return obj.payment_sum

def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    queryset = super().get_queryset(request, *args, **kwargs).annotate(
            payment_amount=Sum('payment__amount'),
            payment_count=Count('payment__subpayment'),
            payment_sum=Sum('payment__subpayment__amount'),
        )
    return queryset
```

I tried use distinct=True , but it remove duplicite subpayments with same amount...

tried on django 2.2 and 3.17

works good:
[image]

works wrong:
[image]
Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way is probably to work with a [**`Subquery`** expressions [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Sum

def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    queryset = super().get_queryset(request, *args, **kwargs).annotate(
        payment_amount=Subquery(
            Payment.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk')).values('user').annotate(
                total=Sum('amount')
            ).values('total').order_by('user')[:1]
        ),
        payment_count=Count('payment__subpayment', distinct=True),
        payment_sum=Subquery(
            SubPayment.objects.filter(payment__user=OuterRef('pk')).values('payment__user').annotate(
                total=Sum('amount')
            ).values('total').order_by('payment__user')[:1]
        )
    )
    return queryset
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help!

The count works well! thanks!, 

but the annotation of subquery returns only first amount of first Subpayment... not a sum, thats weird didnt find out why :-)

Comment: @Linum: what if you add a `.values` clause with the `user`/`payment__user`?

Comment: Wow, looks like works!  I spent a lot of time debugging Django with this problem :-) 

thanks a lot!, you rock! :-)

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem
One more thing .... the subquery is like 10x slower than annotation... i have db with like 10 000 Users ... the time was like 0.5 sec and now its 5 sec... 

any typ how to speed up ? :-) thanks!